# Sorting a list by a element in the sublist

Tags: prolog

This program has an error

```
% Facts:

% the top has no number or directionality
node(top, top, nil).

% messages
node(aleph , 0, out).
node(bet   , 0, in).

node(aleph , 1, out).
node(bet   , 1, in).

node(aleph , 2, out).
node(bet   , 2, in).

node(bottom, bottom, nil).

% predicates/queries
order_nodes(Cpu, Count, [[Cpu | Count] | [] ]) :- node(Cpu, Count, _).
order_nodes(Cpu, Count, [[Cpu | HeadCount] | Rest]) :-
    (   node(Cpu, Count, _),
        integer(HeadCount)
    )
    ->  (   Count < HeadCount,
            order_nodes(Cpu, HeadCount, Rest)
        ),
        true.
```

Error:

```
?- order_nodes(aleph, X, List).
X = 0,
List = [[aleph|0]] ;
X = 1,
List = [[aleph|1]] ;
X = 2,
List = [[aleph|2]] ;
false.
```

The point is to unify `List` with a list of node's values, *in order by the second element*.
. Well, this partially succeeds, but returns false. Performing a trace suggests that the `->` operator is matching a false condition at a certain point and this percolates up the goal tree...

Comment: Is 'false' at the end your only issue? It only means that Prolog couldn't find more solutions after initial three.

Comment: As @SergeyDymchenko is saying, the `false` at the end merely means Prolog failed to find additional solutions after you typed your last `;`. It's normal. It doesn't mean overall failure. Also, your list notation is wrong. `[A|B]` if `B` is not a list should be written `[A,B]`. I think your program otherwise works fine. You can use `findall/3` to capture all the results in a single list, as Boris shows in his answer.

Comment: @SergeyDymchenko: No, thank you. I have many issues. Ignorance with Prolog is only the beginning of them. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a bunch of weird stuff going on in your code, including a weird `->` and the use of `[A | B]` for what seems to be a pair of elements.

So first, you can use `findall/3` like this to collect all nodes, making pairs with the second element as the first element of the pair (so that you can sort on it later):

```
?- findall(Second-node(First, Third), node(First, Second, Third), All).
All = [top-node(top, nil), 0-node(aleph, out), 0-node(bet, in), 1-node(aleph, out),
1-node(bet, in), 2-node(aleph, out), 2-node(bet, in), bottom-node(..., ...)]
```

If you only need the nodes with first element `aleph`:

```
?- First = aleph,
   findall(Second-node(First, Third), node(First, Second, Third), All).
First = aleph,
All = [0-node(aleph, out), 1-node(aleph, out), 2-node(aleph, out)].
```

They happen to be sorted, because this is how the facts are ordered, but you can use the ISO predicate `keysort/2` on your list of pairs:

```
?- First = aleph,
   findall(Second-node(First, Third), node(First, Second, Third), All),
   keysort(All, Sorted).
First = aleph,
All = Sorted, Sorted = [0-node(aleph, out), 1-node(aleph, out), 2-node(aleph, out)].
```

Or, if you don't care about the third argument of your `node/3`,

```
?- First = aleph,
   findall(Second-First, node(First, Second, _), All),
   keysort(All, Sorted).
First = aleph,
All = Sorted, Sorted = [0-aleph, 1-aleph, 2-aleph].
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

PS: you can of course use a compound goal in the second argument to `findall/3`, for example

```
findal(Foo, ( node(A, B, C), integer(B) ), Bar)
```

but I really don't quite understand your reasons for having the `node/3` facts as they are.

Comment: N.b., This is a prototype of a more interesting problem. The `node/3` representation is a concentrated form of what will eventually be a larger system. They take the form they have because that is the form of the facts in their 'world'.  I am building queries on them towards a particular domain specific goal, which I believe to be highly amenable to solving with Prolog.  However, I haven't written Prolog in anger in a decade. :-)

Comment: @PaulNathan So was my answer helpful at all? As far as sorting is concerned, I can't think of a straight-forward way of sorting data represented as facts without first collecting all of it, hence the suggestion to use `findall/3` and `keysort/2`.